# Not able to see the logs of a web application

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have created a web application, below is the entry point of that application

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Routing;
using Microsoft.Graph.Communications.Common.Telemetry;

namespace ProductsApp3
{

    public class WebApiApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        private readonly IGraphLogger logger;
        public WebApiApplication()
        {
            this.logger = 
            new 
     GraphLogger(typeof(WebApiApplication).Assembly.GetName().Name, 
     redirectToTrace: true);
        }
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            this.logger.Info("WorkerRole has been started");
            Console.WriteLine("Sai");
            GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);

        }
    }
}
```

But Nowhere I can see the below statements when I run the application in Visual Studio

```cs
this.logger.Info("WorkerRole has been started");
Console.WriteLine("Sai");"
```

can someone help me please where I can see this log inormation locally and also in AKS if I deploy this app there?.

Comment: Would you mind adding your code as text? Screenreader have a hard time parsing images.

Comment: Is the project you created asp.net?

Comment: Yes, it is an asp.net project.